# AppCompatActivity Error

Tags: android

I am new to Android studio from Eclipse and trying to tweek setup. When I add and Activity (blank activity) it generates the java file but it comes up with extends AppCompatActivity which gives errors.Most of my project use ActionBarActivity or Activity. Is there a setting that I need to address to gernerate these files and eliminate errors ?

Here is the file generated by adding a activity

```
package com.example.jerry.els2015;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Here is the gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.jerry.els2015"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

Comment: please tell us which errors you are seeing

Comment: Cannot resolve AppCompatActivity

Comment: Are you planning on using anything in the support library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might already know, `AppCompatActivity` is part of the support library. I wonder if you have the library downloaded. You could open the SDK manager and scroll all the way to the end to make sure you have it:

[image]
After that you need to include it as a dependency to the gradle build file for the module (not project). In your build.gradle file you need to add:
`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'`

Comment: I want to move in the other direction and setup Android Studio to use Activity and not AppCompatActivity when auto generating these files.

Comment: FYI, Google Repository has been installed in SDK

Comment: There's a check on the Google repository option because the SDK manager suggested me to upgrade my currently installed version. I meant to point the `Android Support Library` option, but based on the replies you made to the other posts in the mean time, I guess you already made sure the version installed on your system matches the one referenced in the gradle file.

Comment: I am not sure how you could change the template generation to use Activity. My assumption was/is that this is determined based on your choice for the minSDK when generating the project. If you were to choose a minSDK of at least 21/Lollippop your activity will extend Activity and not AppCompatActivity.

Comment: I did update SDK and IDE A.S 1.3.1.  restarted A.S and added class and still generates errors with AppCompatActivity. I dont have the knowledge to dig further into the issues as I struggle with simple app coding. Thank you for the replies.

Comment: Ok, now  that you updated to the latest support lib, this version is 22.2.1. Did you make sure that you reference the same version in the build.gradle file? (you had 22.0.0 before). If this does not solve the issue, I would also try one more thing: open a command line prompt in your project root folder and run `gradlew assembleDebug`. The gradle wrapper might be able to fetch any required dependencies. If not, there's always trying to generate a new project since yours seems to be a test project.

Answer (score 2):

Based on whether or not you have a dependency on the support library in your build.gradle, Android Studio will either generate your activity with `extends AppCompatActivity` or `extends Activity`.

Comment: I posted gradle, can I remove any dependancies that will resolve issue ? I dont understand these items so I dont want to make it worse.

Comment: If you are using `ActionBarActivity`, then that is also part of the support library. If you only are going to use `Activity`, you should be able to just delete the `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'` and any future Activity generated will `extends Activity`.

Comment: That worked but also created more problems. I will have to work through this option but thank you for the reference It gave me a boost on how it all works.

Answer (score 0):

At the left projects pane. you will see a project with the name "support-v7-appcompat" on it. double click that to open it.

Answer (score 0):

if your using Gradle

```
dependencies{
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Posted gradle, 7:22.0.0